# Spring boot with shared JavaEE entities jar

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, java-ee-6, openejb

I got a problem where I'm not able to find a solution.
We got a shared library with all entities which are setup to use with JavaEE 6 entities (Websphere). So mapping is based on the JavaEE 6 jpa annotations.

unfortunately this doesn't work out of the box with Spring Boot. Because not all annotations combinations are supported.

e.g.:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne property:`

Used Database is db2. The connection works fine. Only the share entity model does not work out the box.

I'm looking now to use a spring boot application that uses openjpa with a db2 database and a persistence.xml with an external jar file. Someone got any experience with this?

Comment: why didnt you use `@JoinColumn` on the `@OneToOne`? and fix specifics? So it then follows the JPA spec

Comment: We are not able to change the external jar-file

Comment: So the "external jar-file" has got non-compliant code in it? good luck with that. You should define WHAT software gives that error by the way.

Comment: The external jar-file works perfect with other Java EE 6 websphere applications. Spring Boot gives the error stated above. But that is just an example. Entity Annotation Mapping for hibernate and openJPA is unfortunately not the same (it looks like)

Comment: So the problem is with Spring-Boot doing its own error checking ? whereas the real JPA provider just ignores crap metadata. So raise a bug on Spring-Boot. Maybe they have some config to turn off their own checks

Comment: @NeilStockton Sorry that is not what I meant. The error is throw by Hibernate. It is a `org.hibernate.AnnotationException`. And the JavaEE 6 application is using OpenJPA

Comment: If you are looking to use OpenJPA with SpringBoot, why is Hibernate throwing an exception?! Hibernate should not be even mentioned anywhere

Comment: If Hibernate is throwing exceptions, you are using Hibernate, not OpenJPA

Comment: I voted to closed this question and opened a new one. How to get openjpa working with Spring boot and an external jar-file with the persistence-unit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255023/reference-a-jar-file-in-de-persistence-xml-within-a-spring-boot-project